# Error en num_rows en php

Tags: php, mysql

El problema es este:

```
<?php
include '../functions/db.php';
include '../functions/Database.php';

$db = new Database();
$nick = $_POST["nick"];
$consulta = "SELECT cedula FROM pacient WHERE cedula = $nick";
$result = $db->select($consulta);

if( $result->num_rows > 0)
    echo 0;
else
    echo 1;
```

Este mensaje me sale

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\IVSS\app\core\url.php** on line **10**

Comment: El mensaje indica que `$result`  no es un objeto válido. Los motivos pueden ser diversos: falla la conexión a la base de datos, falla la consulta, etc. Recomiendo que implementes la _programación responsable_ es decir, que siempre evalúes tus variables en el código, que las controles y que hagas al código _decir_ en cada momento lo que ocurre. No estás evaluando nada de eso: ni si `$db` es nulo, ni si hay algo en `$nick`, ni si `$result` arroja algo. O sea, estás ejecutando tres acciones de forma _irresponsable_ en tu código, así, ni tú ni el usuario sabrá lo que está pasando cuando haya error

Comment: ¿Qué estás usando? ¿PDO o mysqli? Tal y como te indica @A.Cedano todo apunta a que la llamada a `select` ha sido infructuosa, pero para saber el motivo tienes que indicar qué usas para poder ponerte un ejemplo de cómo averiguar el problema.